# Media player getting IllegalStateException at setDataSource

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, illegalstateexception

I debug and see that `path = /storage/emulated/0/Music/test_cbr.mp3`

and tested

```
mp.setDataSource(path);
```

and

```
mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(),Uri.parse(path));
```

but both ways give illegalStateException at setDataSource Why?

```
try 
        {

            MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

              //  Uri fileUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 1834);

              //  mp.setDataSource(context, fileUri);


            mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

            mp.release();

            mp.reset();

            mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(),Uri.parse(path));

              //  mp.reset();

            //    mp.setDataSource(context, uri);    


            mp.prepare();


            mp.start();

            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
              } catch (SecurityException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
              } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
              } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
              }
```

**Edit and Answer**

Everything is working fine now. I have misspelled mp to mediaplayer. Now i correct it. Thanks for your help friends.

Comment: Could you post your stacktrace of the error as well?

Answer (score 2):

create a global object of media player inside your activity class:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;//global object
String path = "/storage/emulated/0/Music/test_cbr.mp3";
```

write the following code inside oncreate method of your activity class:

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
});
```

i hope this solution can help u.

Answer (score 1):

Just just try my code

```
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    try {

        mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse("path"));
        mp.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mp.start();
```